# Should I use 2x the number of CPU / core for Argon2id parallelism?

Tags: hash, passwords, argon2

I've read that I should use 2x the number of CPU available from some documentation while others suggest using between 1 and the number of CPU.

I realize there is no hard answer here but I'm curious what the advised best practices are. Especially with such a variation in advice.

Comment: Could you edit and show where is the conflict? The 2x should be due to the hyperthreading.

Comment: @kelalaka my apologizes, the conflict is in the information I've read.

Comment: @kelalaka that actually clears it up for me though, thanks. go reports num CPU with hyperthreading factored in. Glad I asked or I would have been doubling over my potential capacity :)

Comment: @kelalaka thanks.

Comment: Welcome. ${}{}{}$